# (Python) Using a for loop to print reoccurring characters in a text file

Tags: python, string, function

I need to make a function that  opens up a text file and prints lines with a specific character in it. After that I need it to print how many times that character is in the entire text document. I developed the function to count how many times a character occurs in a string. here it is:

```
    def countLetterString(char, str):
       if str == "":
          return 0
       elif str[0] == char:
           return 1 + countLetterString(char, str[1:])
       else:
           return countLetterString(char, str[1:])
```

The function I am trying to make is:

```
    def countLetterString(char, Textfilename):
```

It takes a given character opens up a file and prints lines with that character in it using a for loop. I am totally stumped :(

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: I don't know why you need to print lines that contain that character to begin with, but you can just loop through each line in the document with a for loop and increment a counter of how many times it has appeared. Your function doesn't do anything with the file- a file isn't a string.

Comment: Your `countLetterString` could be more succinctly (and somewhat more efficiently, although it's still not optimal) written as `len([x for x in str if x == char])`...

Comment: No it couldn't, `str` is an inbuilt!

Comment: @user2387370 ok, yeah, bad choice of variable name - I blindly copied what was in the function defined above as the string parameter... Other than that, though, it works...

Comment: Your function is written recursively... this is not a good idea in Python, because Python doesn't optimize tail-recursion and has a relatively shallow stack (it will hit stack overflow with a relatively small number of recursive calls).  Also, slicing makes a copy of the data, so this recursive function will cause a lot of "churn" with memory allocated/freed.  It is pretty much the slowest and least efficient solution possible in Python.  Best is to leverage the built-in features of Python, such as the `.count()` method function on iterables, as shown in the @Rohmer answer.

Comment: @twalberg Your code: `len([x for x in str if x == char])` builds a list just to check its length... it will allocate a list, create objects for each character and set them into the list, then free the list and all the character objects.  Lots of "churn" there.  Better would be to just look at the sequence and count things.  I'll use `s` for the string name since `str` is a built-in:  `sum(1 for x in s if x == char)`  This doesn't build and free a list, it makes a generator expression and sums it.  But best of all is to use the built-in `.count()` method as shown in the answer by Rhomer.

Comment: By the way, it's sleazy but this works: if you use `sum()` on objects of type `bool` it will treat a `True` as a 1 and a `False` as a 0.  So you can also write it this way:  `sum(x == char for x in s)`  This is probably the fastest solution that doesn't use the built-in `.count()` method.

Comment: @steveha That's why I commented that it's still not optimal - but it's better than the recursive method in the original post...

Comment: @user2751692 If one of these answers has helped, please mark it as the answer so that other users can quickly find the solution. You can do this for all the questions that you ask here.

Comment: @user2751692 Please choose an answer to resolve this question.

Answer (score 3):

Python has a count method on iterables (a string can be treated as an iterable)

```
char = 'b'
count = 0

f = open('textfile.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    if char in line:
        print line
        count += line.count(char)

print count
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
Usage:
./charinfile.py myfilename char
'''
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]
charac = sys.argv[2]
count=0

with open(filename,"r") as f:

    for line in f:
        count = count + line.count(charac)

print "char count is %s" % count
```

Comment: Why not `count += line.count(charac)`?

Comment: @user2387370 What are the pros and cons of doing that ?

Comment: Pros: it is more readable and shorter (and possibly faster/more memory efficient). Cons: none that I can think of.

Comment: @user2387370 It is really faster/more memory efficient ? Can anybody confirm that please?

Comment: In any case, it is not considerably slower/less memory efficient. Premature optimization (at least at the expense of readablility when you gain hardly anything in speed or memory usage) is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, recursion isn't the best solution, you can just iterate over loops

```
def readCharacters(character,filename):
    f = open('filename','r')
    counter = 0
    for line in f.readlines():

        if character in line:
            print line
        for character in line:
            counter = counter + 1

    return counter

    f.close()
```

Comment: Not that it matters much in this case, but if you put the second for loop under the if statement the loop will only be evaluated when the character is in the line.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:    # opens the file `filename` and allows it to be referenced with the name `f`
    counter = 0                   # initializes the counter of the character as 0
    for line in f:                # (you can iterate directly over files) 
        if character in line:     
            print(line)
            counter += line.count(character)
```

It is best to open a file with a `with` statement because this means it will be closed whatever happens (e.g. even if an exception occurs while the file is being managed).

Your code doesn't seem to make much sense in relation to the problem as I understand it, but this seems most like what you were going for:

```
def countLetterString(char, string):
   if string == "":
      return None   # explicit to be clear
   else:
       return string.count(char)

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    counter = 0
    for line in f:
        count = countLetterString(the_character, line)
        if count:
            print(line)
            counter += count
```

On the off-chance you were looking for a recursive solution (you probably weren't):

```
def count_and_print(file_object, character):
    def do_line(file, counter):
        line = file.readline()
        if line:
            if character in line:
                print(line)
                return do_line(file, counter + line.count(character))
        else:
            return counter
    return do_line(file_object, 0)
```

Comment: I appreciate the help I just got a little stuck on something I also created a main function that calls countLetterFile('o', 'some.txt') but it is printing the lines but not returning the counter. if I just call the countLetterfile outside the main function it does why is this?

Comment: I'd imagine you don't have a return statement. Maybe you could edit your post to have the code for the main function?

Comment: This  is what is happening https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c2f1db67da5c4cb4959a

Comment: Yes, you need `def main(): return countLetterFile('o', 'some.txt')`. Also, replace `open('some.txt','r')` with `open(textFileName,'r')`, otherwise the function will only work for files called some.txt!